# Whitelist Controller Action in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question about the `[Authorization]` annotation. I have a controller with the `[Authorization(Roles ="admin")` annotation. In the controller I have one action that doesn't need to be admin, but still logged in. How is this done? I have tried creating a custom `AuthorizationAttribute` class, and placing it on the action. This doesn't work, is there a way to override the `[Authorization]` annotation?

Cheers.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{ 
    [OwnDataAuthorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id)
        {
             //.....
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Creating a custom class should work properly. You have to design two custom classes. First will act as **AuthorizationAttribute** and second will be just a identifier attribute (say **IgnoreRoleAttribute**)  which you have to place on the action where you don't want any role to be checked. Then while authorizing you can check if the source action method has the IgnoreRoleAttribute applied to it and you can skip role authorization here :)

Comment: What I have there worked, but I needed to implement another interface in my custom class because of a bug with mvc 5. source: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/new-filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-web-api-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/new-filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-web-api-2). I was doing it correctly but because of a bug with mvc 5 I had to implement another interface as well in my custom class:

```
public class OwnDataAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute, IOverrideFilter {
//....
/// <summary>
        /// Only implemented because of a bug in MVC 5.
        /// </summary>
        public System.Type FiltersToOverride
        {
            get { return typeof (IAuthenticationFilter); }
        }
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to MVC 5.1 or 5.1.2

Comment: Yeah, I heard it was fixed in 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a **simple** way to do this, except for moving the `Authorize` attribute into every controller method/action. So you would need to remove the `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` and add it to every method except for the one you want to authorize.

A work around would be to use the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute with an if statement inside the controller action to check for `IsAuthenticated`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        //redirect to loging
    //other logic here
    ...
}
```

Comment: What I have there worked, but I needed to implement another interface in my custom class because of a bug with mvc 5. [source](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/new-filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-web-api-2)